# "Caldoniafied" In General Use in the 1980s?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, slang

I am curious about the word "Caldoniafied" meaning, roughly, hard headed, and presumably coming from the song entitled "Caldonia"  ("Caldonia, Caldonia, what makes your big head so hard?". )Louis Jordan had a big hit with it, and BB King still sings it. This word was used by my Brooklyn landlady in the 1980s. Was it in general use at this time?  Also, was it a huge insult? I am writing a novel set at this time and wanted to use it as a light term. Google doesn't have much about it.

Comment: I have a vague memory of an famous early English author talking about the certitude and literal-mindedness of men from Caledonia. The idea is the Caledonians never understood anything but completely, and with perfect certainty, and would never speak of anything they did not understand to this extent; but the joke was they could not understand metaphor or figurative speech. It flew right over their heads. I want to say Robert Burns, but I don't think that's right. Anyway, someone 18th- or 17th-century.

Comment: @DanBron - I think you may be under the misapprehension that the OP has mistyped *Caldonia* when she meant *Caledonia*. This is not the case: I am familiar with the Louis Jordan performance, and it's definitely *Caldonia*.

Comment: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldonia), [lyrics](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Louis_Jordan:Caldonia), [essay](http://www.loc.gov/rr/record/nrpb/registry/essays/Caldonia.pdf), [stamp](http://www.encyclopediaofarkansas.net/encyclopedia/media-detail.aspx?mediaID=7771).

Comment: Following up on my earlier comment, in his essay [*Imperfect Sympathies*, Charles Lamb](http://www.ourcivilisation.com/smartboard/shop/lamb/sympathy.htm) pokes fun at Scotsmen aka Cal**e**donians, as being completely literal-minded. This may have been the work I was thinking of, or it could have been a contemporary or later essay which [made allusion to it](http://j.mp/1E1klpc), but I'm still not totally convinced what the original piece I had run across was.

Comment: @Dan: Do you know the Lord Peter Wimsey stories? He has a brother-in-law, I think, whose hobby is reading sermons of 18th-century Scottish ministers, yikes. And Chesterton refers to the Presbyterian divine ending his hours-long sermon with "Seventeenthly and lastly", finding it appalling but at the same time a compliment to the Scottish listener's powers of concentration. Not exactly the attention deficit generation!

Comment: @DavidPugh I don't know the Whimsy stories (in on the wrong side of the pond for that), but now I'm gonna go google them!

Comment: @Dan: If you read them as well as Googling, my own favourite is "Gaudy Night". (That's the name of an Oxford celebration, gaudy is not acting as a lush adjective.) Watch the spelling, author is Dorothy Sayers, who worked in an ad agency ("Murder Must Advertise") and did the then definitive translation of "The Divine Comedy". Enjoy!

Comment: Appending "fied" or "ified" to a name (or forming some sort of portmanteau, a la "Californicate") is a fairly common practice, and a particular instance of this may gain some currency in a given locality for a limited amount of time. Such terms rarely become well-known outside of a small area or social group, however.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the term "Caldoniafied," even in a lighthearted way. In the first place, I'm not aware that the expression was ever common in the United States, either during the 1980s (I spent 1980–81 in Washington, D.C.; 1982–84 in Staten Island, New York; and 1985–89 in Berkeley, California) or afterward.

A Google search turns up just one match for *Caldoniafied* and none for *Caldoniafy*. From Ed Ward, "Dedicated to You," in Greil Marcus, ed., [*Stranded: Rock and Roll for a Desert Island*](http://books.google.com/books?id=0dsVOtM-Q3UC&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=%22Caldoniafied%22&source=bl&ots=LX2p98to3p&sig=jd16gEofXbWk4ZFIZC4UoimUu_4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9xR9VN-PLZTtoAS12ILICA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Caldoniafied%22&f=false) (1979):

> One night, as they were leaving the backstage of a show, a teenager had called Obediah [Carter, who sang tenor for the "5" Royales] "an old Caldoniafied nigger," and the rest of the guys had to hold him back to keep him from outright throttling the kid.

This incident occurred sometime in late 1959 or early 1960. It's not clear to me what exactly the teenager meant by "Caldoniafied." Since Louis Jordan sang comic and novelty songs (as the "5" Royales often did a decade later), and since Jordan's vocals launched into the high tenor range on "[Caldonia](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PR6pHtiNT_k)" (as Carter's did on various songs in the "5" Royales repertoire), perhaps the kid was implying that Carter was stealing his singing style from Jordan and that the style was in any case behind the times. Or perhaps the kid simply meant that Carter and the other Royales were hopelessly hardheaded in refusing to adapt to the fundamental changes then occurring in R&B and rock. In any event, the remark didn't sit well with Obediah Carter, and I don't get the impression that the choice of "Caldoniafied" as a modifier softened the blow of the ultimate racial epithet.

It would be difficult (I think) to use "Caldoniafied" today in a non-race-inflected way. The OP's Brooklyn landlady may have pulled it off, but for anyone who has committed Louis Jordan's "Caldonia! Caldonia! What makes your big head so hard?" to memory, it is hard not to think of Caldonia as anything but a lean, lanky, hardheaded Black woman (with great big feet)—even though Jordan never specifies her race or color. In a culture sensitized to and uneasy about the implications of racial innuendo, I would do my best to steer clear of "Caldoniafied," "Jemimafied," "Porgyfied," "Rochesterfied," and the like as if they were so many land mines.